# Tools for Apache Cordova in VS2017 - using remotebuild with Macincloud gives Operation has timed out

Tags: visual-studio-cordova, cordova-ios

After installing VS2017 on my Win10 machine I created a blank cordova project. I setup a MacInCloud Managed server, and configured the host and certificates per the [Docs](http://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build_ios_cloud/).  I filled out the Remote Agent Configuration in VS with the host and PIN and all seemed to work fine.

I select iOS for the platform and "Simulator - iPhone5" and push play.

The build starts with the following output:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sending the build to the remote build server
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
------ Incremental Build: False
------ Submitting new build request to: https://SE529.macincloud.com:3000/cordova/build/tasks?command=build&vcordova=6.3.1&cfg=debug
```

and the remotebuild terminal looks to be hearing the request and outputs this:

```
New build request submitted:
/build/tasks?command=build&vcordova=6.3.1&cfg=debug
{"content-type":"multipart/form-data;","host":"se529.macincloud.com:3000","content-length":"69009422","expect":"100-continue","connection":"Keep-Alive"}
Build will be executed under: /Users/user905423/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/47678
Saving build request payload to : /Users/user905423/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/47678
```

However, it just sits there for about 90 seconds, and finally the VS output window prints this:

```
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : An error occurred uploading to the build server https://SE529.macincloud.com:3000/cordova/build/tasks?command=build&vcordova=6.3.1&cfg=debug: The operation has timed out
------ 04/11/2017 13:45:07 Checking on build status from  [Attempt 1]
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.FileMirroring.targets(256,5): error MSB4018: The "VsTac" task failed unexpectedly.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.FileMirroring.targets(256,5): error MSB4018: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.FileMirroring.targets(256,5): error MSB4018: Parameter name: requestUriString
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.FileMirroring.targets(256,5): error MSB4018:    at System.Net.WebRequest.Create(String requestUriString)
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.FileMirroring.targets(256,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.MultiDeviceHybridApps.MdaBuildTasks.RemoteBuild.CreateWebRequest(String url)
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.FileMirroring.targets(256,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.MultiDeviceHybridApps.MdaBuildTasks.RemoteBuild.PollForBuildComplete(String buildingUrl, Int32 interval, Int32 attempts)
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.FileMirroring.targets(256,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.MultiDeviceHybridApps.MdaBuildTasks.RemoteBuild.Build()
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.FileMirroring.targets(256,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.MultiDeviceHybridApps.MdaBuildTasks.VsTac.BuildPlatform()
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.FileMirroring.targets(256,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.MultiDeviceHybridApps.MdaBuildTasks.VsTac.Execute()
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.FileMirroring.targets(256,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.FileMirroring.targets(256,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext()
1>Done building project "HSS.CordovaApp.jsproj" -- FAILED.
========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

And then the remotebuild terminal window on the Mac shows this:

```
POST /cordova/build/tasks?command=build&vcordova=6.3.1&cfg=debug - - ms - -
```

My attempts to google the problem found that a recent update to the remotebuild agent increased the timeouts on listeners, and I have confirmed that the version of remotebuild installed on my managed Mac instance has that update.

I have confirmed that the upload has at least started, I can see the file ~/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/47678/upload_47678.tgz".  It almost feels like the upload completes but VS does not hear back from the remoteBuild agent?

Perhaps there are special steps required to use remoteBuild on MacInCloud for Cordova iOS builds?  Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Bump - same issue for me. Did you resolve this one Andy?

Comment: @timk  - I did not find a proper solution to this issue.  I eventually tried creating a completely blank Cordova project and built that fine.  I came to the conclusion that simply adding the Azure Mobile plugin and it's dependencies made it so large that it could not be uploaded in 90 seconds.
I also could not find a way to test an app on a USB connected device using MacInCloud, so at that point I gave up on the service.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my problem of Operation timeout by extending the timeout parameter in remotebuild.config inside mac to 600000. pls try the same